# Onchange event of dropdown in server side datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

This is my codeignitor datatable(http://postimg.org/image/jptkczs8p/).I m trying to create an event on status dropdown change.all dropdown has same class.its looks like dropdown is not at all connected to this script.m i missing something.please help.

here is my code which does nothing.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
$('.status_c').on("change", function() { 
    //alert("i m working");
    var id = this.attr('id');
    var value =  this.val();
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //document.getElementById('group_info').style.display='none';
    //document.getElementById('library_info').style.display='block';
    //document.getElementById("model_body1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo base_url();?>records/changestatus?id="+id+"&value="+value+"",true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
});
});
```

This is my controller

```
function changestatus()
  {
      $ids = $this->input->get('id');
      $values = $this->input->get('value');

      $data = array(
           'status' =>$values               
        );

     $this->db->where('id', $ids);
     $this->db->update('complaint', $data); 

     echo "complain updated";


  }
```

here is script for server side datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';    

var ETable = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy",
    "processing": true,
    "bSort": false, 
            "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
            ],
            "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url();?>records/numlistajax",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100], [10, 25, 50,100]],                
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "aaSorting": [[3, 'asc']],
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',                
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "oLanguage": {
            "sInfoFiltered": "",
    "sProcessing": "<img style='position:absolute;' src='<?php echo base_url();?>public/img/loading.gif'>"
            },
            "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
});


});
```

Comment: what is showing you in alert?

Comment: "complain updated" imran.this issue is solved minor error in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a small change in script of onchange event

```
 $(document).on("change", ".status_c", function() {
```

and not this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
$('.status_c').on("change", function() {
```